# CellTable: Data repeats in all Columns

Tags: gwt, celltable

i'm a newbie here and in GWT.
Well, i have some questions with CellTable... And i'm very upset with the problem.
The problem is: When i make a setRowData or ListDataProvider.setList, all the data in the List i have repeats at all Columns. If i have 11 datas on the list, all 11 data repeats in 11 rows and all columns.
To explain better, the image of issue.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/celltable.jpg/

I don't know what i have to do to resolve this type of "problem".
Anyway, i will post  the code:

//TABLE CODE

```
    tablePesquisaResultados = new CellTable<String>();
    tablePesquisaResultados.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.BOUND_TO_SELECTION);
    tablePesquisaResultados.setTableLayoutFixed(true);
    tablePesquisaResultados.setKeyboardPagingPolicy(KeyboardPagingPolicy.INCREASE_RANGE);
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 0, tablePesquisaResultados);

    SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
    SimplePager pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 10, true);
    pager.setDisplay(tablePesquisaResultados);

    tablePesquisaResultados.setWidth("1262px");

    colID = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colID, "ID");

    colNomeUsuario = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colNomeUsuario, "Nome do Usuário");

    colEmail = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colEmail, "Email");

    colCodigoUsuario = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colCodigoUsuario, "Código do Usuário");

    colTelefone = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colTelefone, "Telefone");

    colCodigoSituacao = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colCodigoSituacao, "Código da Situação");

    colDataAbertura = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colDataAbertura, "Data de Abertura");

    colDataEncerramento = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colDataEncerramento, "Data de Encerramento");

    colDescricao = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colDescricao, "Descrição do Chamado");

    colMidiaAnexada = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colMidiaAnexada, "Mídia Anexada");

    colStatusID = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
    tablePesquisaResultados.addColumn(colStatusID, "Status ID");
    flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(2, 0, 2);
    FlexTableHelper.fixRowSpan(flexTable);
```

//END TABLE CODE

//CODE TO INSERT DATA IN CELLTABLE

```
        ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();     
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(tablePesquisaResultados);
    dataProvider.setList(resultado);
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

//END CODE TO INSERT DATA IN CELLTABLE

Well, there is.

Thanks, in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for each column you use the same `getValue` function:

```
@Override
public String getValue(String object) {
   return object.toString();
}
```

You need specific functions for each column that return the value that you want to display in that column. For example for column `colNomeUsuario`:

```
colNomeUsuario = new TextColumn<String>() {
   @Override
   public String getValue(String object) {
      return object.getNomeUsuario();
   }
};
```

**Edit**

I just noticed the way you define your celltable:

```
tablePesquisaResultados = new CellTable<String>();
```

You need to define it like this:

```
tablePesquisaResultados = new CellTable<MyObject>();
```

Where MyObject is a class representing the information that you want to display in the celltable.

You can pass server objects to the client side using [Request Factory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html), or [GWT RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).

Comment: Wow! This helps a lot. But.. another thing. how i will pass a Object with gets/sets to client-side?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have to modify my entity class, because of the annotations, i can't serialize the object. DTO design is better than DAO in this case?

Comment: DAO is a good pattern because of the separation of concerns principle. The fact is that you may end up needing DTOs even when implementing DAO. That's one reason the GWT team added [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html). See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564568/gwt-rpc-dto-vs-dao).

Comment: Hum. And the persistence? i can use JPA normally or i have to consider use Hibernate?

Comment: thanks a lot. I resolved my problem and a tons of others. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.