# Why is the DTO an anti-pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, dto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Data Transfer Objects an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440952/why-are-data-transfer-objects-an-anti-pattern)

While reading this good question with great answers:

[Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

User Pascal Thivent (150K rep) says in his answer with 31 upvotes (and 16 favorites) that the DTO is an anti-pattern.

Can someone explain why the DTO is an anti-pattern and what are the alternatives?

Comment: @Faust: ah cool thanks a lot, this question can then be closed : )