# Java: Persistence Class with toDTO method categorized as adapter pattern?

Tags: java, adapter, dto

If i have an Persistence class which implements a method "toDTO" and this method return a POJO representing the object, will this be categorized as an adapter pattern?

Please note, that this is not a question of the implementation as such, but rather in which way it would be categorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DTO uses the live state of the Persistence object then this may be classified as an adapter; if it makes a defensive copy of the data, discarding the original, then it is not an adapter.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your point, would it be a bother to clarify a little? (sorry for the late reply)

i mean its a pojo so it would always be regarded as a defensive copy, or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: If the DTO doesn't hold a reference to the persistence object, then there can definitely be no word of the *Adapter* pattern at work.

Comment: Well in my case, it will hold an id referencing the object in db. so that would definitely be adapter pattern?

Comment: That's an extralinguistic reference, it has nothing to do with OOP patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Note that DTO is usually classified as a pattern on itself. See Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440952/why-are-data-transfer-objects-an-anti-pattern) for discussion about DTO being an anti-pattern.