# retreiving object from controller in spring mvc via ajax call with no data

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have one jsp page, on load of jsp, two radio button is there, on click of first radio button, i am doing an ajax call with no data and it will go to controller and method will return a list object but it is not even hitting the controller method

My ajax code is like this :

```
 $("#radio1").click(function(){
    alert('success');   
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'ConnectionStringDetails',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){   
            alert('True');

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('unsuccessfull');
            }
    });
```

and controller method is like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/ConnectionStringDetails")
@ResponseBody
public List<ConnectionString> ConnectionStringDetails()
{

    List<ConnectionString> conndetail=null;
    System.out.println("ConnectionStringDetails");

        conndetail=bdpService.getSourcesData();

    return conndetail;
}
```

Comment: what does the browser network call view show?

Comment: Need more details... Do you have any mapping on the controller? How are you running the app? Do you have web.xml? What url do you see in the browser debugger?

Comment: @Rohit : it is not showing any data in n/w call view, just showing the method name i.e ConnectionStringDetails

Comment: @jny, yes, web.xml is there but m using RequestMapping annotation for mapping and same passing in url of ajax call, other ajax calls in project in which m passing data is working, only this one (with no data), is giving problem.

Comment: @rohit, when m clicking on radio button, it is just showing that alert('success') and then unsuccessfull

Comment: now, in n/w, it is showing this exception on clicking of the method:       HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:

Comment: @Rohit actually, problem is with controller because of the List return type, if m giving return type is string, it is working fine but i need list of objects to be returned

Comment: @Kirti, are you using Hibernate or something similar?  If yes, you have to figure out how you want to deal with lazy initialization. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360216/mvc-with-lazy-loading