# ASP.NET API make payload model optional conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, payload

I have an API Controller, which has the following 2 APIs, Add & Update.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] ToDO todo) 
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update([FromBody] ToDO todo)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I've used a single Entity, ToDO, in both Add & Update APIs. Definition for ToDO is as following

```
public class ToDO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [**Required**]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [**Required**]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

In the ToDO class both the properties are mandatory, as we're using it for the Add operation. But for Update, any 1 of the property could be blank/null. However, if I use the same model during Update, I'm required to send all the properties in the payload again!

I can use 2 separate models 1 for Add and another 1 for Update. However, it will duplicate the model code.

How can I reuse the same model. But the required attribute should also be there otherwise will have to check !string.IsNullOrEmpty for all the properties, during Add, which is not feasible.
I've used a dummy class here. Actual project class as 20+ properties.

So, 2 main questions

- How can I re-use same model for Add/Update with dynamic Required attributes.
- Is sending the entire payload during Update optimal? We should be able to send only the modified properties and not all.

Plz advice.

Comment: See answer and comments here [should I have different DTOs for Create and update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073058/should-i-have-different-dtos-for-create-and-update-crud)

Comment: Have you thought about custom model binding? It is efficient in eliminating repetitive code.

Comment: @IbramReda Thnx for sharing the link. However, in the link, the property in question is ID so they're working with default value using the same DTO. However, in my case there are multiple properties. Thanks.

Comment: @Ronaldoz I'm not sure about custom bindings. Can ypu plz share any sample link for the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Ronaldoz custom model binding is fine. But I'm not sure if we can mark the properties Required conditionally in it. Can you plz provide an example for the same.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to look into other validation mechanism instead of build-in one, like FluentValidation. In FluentValidation it's be easy to have one DTO class and different validation rule sets based on use case of the DTO.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not supported to simply make a dynamic model validation attribute of Required, to apply one single model to different methods of different nullable validation. You need to use custom bindings, which needs a certain amount of code, or do validations in controllers. Here is the document:   https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

More important, it violates the design concept of asp.net core MVC. It makes decoupling difficult. We are supposed to use models/view/controllers independently. The later maintenance of code will be more difficult if we do so.

Second, it is indeed better to reduce the payload, which will reduce network bandwidth consumption and improve transmission efficiency, reduce server load and improve responsiveness. We can use JsonPatch to do it.

Add the service in program.cs and download the package:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/

Then we can add the operations to payload through json.

```
[HttpPatch]
public IActionResult Patch(long id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<TodoItem> patchDocument)
{
    if (patchDocument != null)
    {
        var customer = new TodoItem();

        patchDocument.ApplyTo(customer, ModelState);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        //send to database
        //...
        return new ObjectResult(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the payload is specific:

[image]
[image]

For more details, here is the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks for the example. As I understand it, will check for Model validation for Add operation only. And for update, I can skip this check as will send only the updated values. Just want to check one thing, what's the standard recommendation in these cases? Is JsonPatchDocument the only way? Thanks.

Comment: You could use viewmodel, which differs from datamodel in logic. To reduce the payload, you can also refer to the Response Compression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0